# What do the badges mean during loading / picking a pokemon in Pokemon Unite?

Tags: pokemon-unite

I have no screenshot at the moment, nor could I find it online. However, if you played the game, you might have seen it yourself. Its location is more at the top border of the "card".

I do not mean the badges after the game btw, but before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you be talking about the lane selection ?

[image]

On the screen, you can see a purple icon on the top left corner of the selected Charizard. This icon shows the lane the player plans to go to. After pressing ZL, when the battle prep menu appears, the 4th option is to select the lane.

- Orange = top lane
- Blue = center lane (also called jungle)
- Purple = bottom lane

Note: this option is unavailable in quick match.

Comment: That's it, now it makes sense I don't see them all the time. Because more often we just pick what is needed after starting.

Answer (score 3):

### The badges in the loading screen represent the rank of the players.

An orange border is for beginner rank.

A red top right corner means Great rank.

A teal top right corner means Expert rank.

A single foldover with a blue edge and purple in the top right corner means Veteran rank.

Two foldovers, one orange, one pink, in the top right corner means Ultra rank.

Three foldovers, one teal, one orange, one blue, in the top right corner indicate Master rank.

Comment: Not part of the answer, but this is usually super useful in determining which lanes might need extra help and what kind of play you can expect from players.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that also the symbols in selection screen are different from the ones in the loading screen. I now figured out the ones in the loading screen are describing a skin and more specific: which skin set they belong to.

[image]

As Unown K answered the symbols during selection are lanes and the borders during loading describe rank.

Here is an image with all different skins:

[image]